# Roots of system of integrals depending on parameters

Tags: integration, systems-of-equations, roots

While working on one problem I have obtained this system of equations:
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
F_1(a,b) &=& \int_0^1 e^{-ax-b} e^{Ax+B+C(1+x^5)^2} dx &=& 1 \\ F_2(a,b) &=& \int_0^1 x e^{-ax-b} e^{Ax+B+C(1+x^5)^2} dx &=& \frac{1}{2} 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$A, B, C$ are constants here. If $C=0$, $(a=A,b=B)$ is a solution (not sure if a single one though).

What could be the methods to find parameters $a, b$ in general (arbitrary $C$)?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the optimal solution using Newton's method. Here is the sketch: by Taylor expansion,
$$
f(x) \approx f(x_i) + f'(x_i)(x-x_i)
$$
At optimum, we want $f(x)=0$,
so given an initial solution $x_i$, one can find next solution $x_{i+1}$ by solving equation
$$
f(x_i) + f'(x_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i) = 0
$$
The sequence $\{x_i\}, i=0,1,\dots$ converges to optimal solution.

The thing which scared me was the integral, but in this case it is valid to differentiate under it, e.g.
$$
\left[\int_0^1 \exp\left\{-ax-b\right\} \exp\left\{Ax+B+C\left(1+x^5\right)^2 \right\} dx\right]'_a \\
= \int_0^1 \left[\exp\left\{-ax-b\right\}\right]'_a \exp\left\{Ax+B+C\left(1+x^5\right)^2 \right\} dx
$$
I have used numeric integration to estimate the function values and derivatives for given parameters $(a, b)$ [like the one in the above equation].